# Weighted Portmanteau Test for Fitted GARCH process

Tags: r, time-series

I have fitted a GARCH process to a time series and analyzed the ACF for squared and absolute residuals to check the model goodness of fit. But I also want to do a formal test and after searching the internet, The Weighted Portmanteau Test (originally by Li and Mak) seems to be the one.

It's from the WeightedPortTest package and is one of the few (perhaps the only one?) that properly tests the GARCH residuals.

While going through the instructions in various documents I can't wrap my head around what the "h.t" argument wants. It says in the info in R that I need to assign "a numeric vector of the conditional variances". This may be simple to an experienced user, though I'm struggling to understand. What is it that I need to do and preferably how would I code it in R?

Thankful for any kind of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken directly from the documentation:

*h.t: a numeric vector of the conditional variances*

A little toy example using the `fGarch` package follows:

```
library(fGarch)
library(WeightedPortTest)

spec <- garchSpec(model = list(alpha = 0.6, beta = 0))
simGarch11 <- garchSim(spec, n = 300)
fit <- garchFit(formula = ~ garch(1, 0), data = simGarch11)

Weighted.LM.test(fit@residuals, fit@h.t, lag = 10)
```

And using `garch()` from the `tseries` package:

```
library(tseries)
fit2 <- garch(as.numeric(simGarch11), order = c(0, 1))
summary(fit2)

# comparison of fitted values:
tail(fit2$fitted.values[,1]^2)
tail(fit@h.t)

# comparison of residuals after unstandardizing:
unstd <- fit2$residuals*fit2$fitted.values[,1] 
tail(unstd)
tail(fit@residuals)

Weighted.LM.test(unstd, fit2$fitted.values[,1]^2, lag = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah as I said, the documentation has been studied without being able to understand. Do you by any change know what h.t means in practice? My guess is that it collects the conditional variance for each observation and matches that with the calculated variance from the GARCH?

I've been using the garch() method in class for the tseries package (outdated I suppose). Can you retrieve h.t in a similar way there? garch() doesn't return a S4 object so the "@" approach doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: h.t is just the estimated conditional variance. I have updated the answer with `garch()`.

Comment: Thanks again! Last question, how come you get NA on the weighted X-squared and therefore also the P-value when you run the test? I tried removing the missing value from the vector but it didn't do the trick. I suppose it should state a number and not NA? - Thanks alot

Comment: The code supplied works and gives you p-values, but it's true that `fit2$residuals`, `fit2$fitted.values` will have `NA` in the first row (a feature of `garch()`). I don't know what went wrong in your case.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! I had to restart the R session (for some reason) and then the test started spitting out p-values. Thank you so much for the help. A life saver to say the least :)

Comment: You are welcome :) But check out `fGarch()` too, I think it's nicer and gives a lot of good output as default.